# Ultimately installing a PECL extension but need a new version of libtool > 2.2

Tags: apt-get, pecl

**What's my end game :**

installing SSPLUS, a PCEL extension

**My config :**
A virtuozzo server running Linux 2.6.18-028stab069.6 (Debian Lenny ??)

**What I've done :**

**1**

```
pear install spplus
```

Deprecated: Directive 'register_long_arrays' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

Deprecated: Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

No releases available for package "pear.php.net/spplus" - package pecl/spplus can be installed with "pecl install spplus"

install failed

**2**

```
pecl install spplus
```

.....

4 source files, building

running: phpize

sh: phpize: command not found

ERROR: `phpize' failed

**3**

After some research I found that I had to install php5-dev (or devel). So, here I go

```
apt-get install php5-dev
```

apt-get install php5-dev

....

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  php5-dev: Depends: libtool (>= 2.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

**4**

I tried apt-get libtool but all I get is libtool 1.5.26-4+lenny1

I find on another question here to tried :

apt-get update
   apt-get upgrade

and re-installing libtool, but I always get the same version.

I don't really understand apt-get so I don't really know what to do

my apt/sources.list :

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-volatile lenny/volatile main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-security lenny/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb http://autoinstall.plesk.com/debian/PSA10 lenny all
```